# laravel 5 PasswordController Route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

in laravel 5 i try the PasswordController and the ResetsPasswords but always i have a route probleme

Route.php

```
Route::controllers(['uses' => 'Auth/PasswordController']);

Route::get('home/ResetsPasswords',array('as'=>'getEmail' ,'uses' => 'home/ResetsPasswords@getEmail') );

Route::post('home/ResetsPasswords',array('as'=>'postEmail' ,'uses' => 'home/ResetsPasswords@postEmail' ));

Route::get('home/ResetsPasswords/{token}',array('as' => 'getReset','uses' => 'home/ResetsPasswords@getReset' ) );

Route::post('home/ResetsPasswords/{token}', array(  'as' => 'postReset','uses' => 'home/ResetsPasswords@postReset'));

Route::get('home/ResetsPasswords',array('as'=>'getEmailSubject' ,'uses' => 'home/ResetsPasswords@getEmailSubject') );

Route::get('home/ResetsPasswords',array('as'=>'redirectPath' ,'uses' => 'home/ResetsPasswords@redirectPath') );
```

The PasswordController.php

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;
class PasswordController extends Controller
{


   use ResetsPasswords;


   public function __construct()
   {
       $this->middleware('guest');
   }
}
```

the ResetsPasswords.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

class PasswordController extends Controller
{
   /*
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | Password Reset Controller
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |
   | This controller is responsible for handling password reset requests
   | and uses a simple trait to include this behavior. You're free to
   | explore this trait and override any methods you wish to tweak.
   |
   */

   use ResetsPasswords;

   /**
    * Create a new password controller instance.
    *
    * @return void
    */
   public function __construct()
   {
       $this->middleware('guest');
   }
}

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

class PasswordController extends Controller
{
   /*
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | Password Reset Controller
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |
   | This controller is responsible for handling password reset requests
   | and uses a simple trait to include this behavior. You're free to
   | explore this trait and override any methods you wish to tweak.
   |
   */

   use ResetsPasswords;

   /**
    * Create a new password controller instance.
    *
    * @return void
    */
   public function __construct()
   {
       $this->middleware('guest');
   }
}


ResetsPasswords.php

        <?php

    //namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Mail\Message;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

    trait ResetsPasswords
    {
       /**
        * Display the form to request a password reset link.
        *
        * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
        */
       public function getEmail()
       {
           return view('auth.password');
       }

       /**
        * Send a reset link to the given user.
        *
        * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
        * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
        */
       public function postEmail(Request $request)
       {
           $this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required|email']);

           $response = Password::sendResetLink($request->only('email'), function (Message $message) {
               $message->subject($this->getEmailSubject());

           });

           switch ($response) {
               case Password::RESET_LINK_SENT:
                   return redirect()->back()->with('status', trans($response));

               case Password::INVALID_USER:
                   return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['email' => trans($response)]);
           }
       }

       /**
        * Get the e-mail subject line to be used for the reset link email.
        *
        * @return string
        */
       protected function getEmailSubject()
       {
           return isset($this->subject) ? $this->subject : 'Your Password Reset Link';
       }

       /**
        * Display the password reset view for the given token.
        *
        * @param  string  $token
        * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
        */
       public function getReset($token = null)
       {
           if (is_null($token)) {
               throw new NotFoundHttpException;
           }

           return view('auth.reset')->with('token', $token);
       }

       /**
        * Reset the given user's password.
        *
        * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
        * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
        */
       public function postReset(Request $request)
       {
           $this->validate($request, [
               'token' => 'required',
               'email' => 'required|email',
               'password' => 'required|confirmed',
           ]);

           $credentials = $request->only(
               'email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'
           );

           $response = Password::reset($credentials, function ($user, $password) {
               $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
           });

           switch ($response) {
               case Password::PASSWORD_RESET:
                   return redirect($this->redirectPath());

               default:
                   return redirect()->back()
                               ->withInput($request->only('email'))
                               ->withErrors(['email' => trans($response)]);
           }
       }

       /**
        * Reset the given user's password.
        *
        * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword  $user
        * @param  string  $password
        * @return void
        */
       protected function resetPassword($user, $password)
       {
           $user->password = bcrypt($password);

           $user->save();

           Auth::login($user);
       }

       /**
        * Get the post register / login redirect path.
        *
        * @return string
        */
       public function redirectPath()
       {
           if (property_exists($this, 'redirectPath')) {
               return $this->redirectPath;
           }

           return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/home';
       }
    }
```

and for the views 
first the emails/password.blade.php

```
<?php
Click here to reset your password: {{ url('password/reset/'.$token) }}
?>
```

the auth/password.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">Reset Password</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    @if (session('status'))
      <div class="alert alert-success">
             {{ session('status') }}
      </div>
    @endif

    @if (count($errors) > 0)
       <div class="alert alert-danger">
       <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
       <ul>
           @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
           @endforeach
        </ul>
        </div>
      @endif

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="/password/email">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>
<div class="col-md-6">
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
         Send Password Reset Link
</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

@endsection
```

the reset.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
 <div class="panel panel-default">
 <div class="panel-heading">Reset Password</div>
 <div class="panel-body">

 @if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
    <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
              <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
         </ul>
        </div>
@endif

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="/password/reset">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $token }}">

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>
<div class="col-md-6">
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>
<div class="col-md-6">
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
</div>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
 <div class="col-md-6">
 <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation">
 </div>
  </div>

 <div class="form-group">
 <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
             Reset Password
 </button>
 </div>
 </div>
 </form>

 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

and finally my login view

```
<a href="{{action("home.ResetsPasswords@getEmail")}}">Mot de passe oublié?</a>
```

so the error is

Call to undefined method Laravel\Routing\Route::controllers()

can you please help me :/ i try to change the route many time but always the same problem !!!!!!!
    thank you

Answer (score 0):

Implicit controllers are deprecated on Laravel 5. You need to remove this:

```
Route::controllers(['uses' => 'Auth/PasswordController']);
```

More info: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-model-binding

Answer (score 0):

This is for laravel 5

```
Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

This is for laravel 5.2

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::controllers([
        'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
        'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
    ]);
});
```

Comment: the same message also when i change it 

`
Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);`
Call to undefined method Laravel\Routing\Route::controllers()

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using in routes.php

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Route;

Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

if you use this then the error comes.
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Route::controllers()

to avoid this error use this

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

Note:Dont need to import anything route 
leave it as
The below one also works

```
Route::controllers([
        'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
        'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
    ]);
```

Comment: i did not import anything in route 
i try  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route; 
same Error message

Comment: which version of laravel you are using?  laravel 5 or 5.1 or 5.2